# Getting crossDomain after login section

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im doing a crossdomain request trought my node.js server but the website requires login to get the messages.

Every thing i did try i couldn't get in the message section 
I only get the statis html with this

```
        request.post("http://webchat.chatbelgie.be/", {
            autoconnect: 1,
            channel: "chat.be",
            nick: "Polar"
        }, function(err, data){
            console.log(data)
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an IRC chat.

You might be more lucky to try and use the IRC protocol directly, with the help of the [`irc` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/irc)

```
var irc = require('irc');
var client = new irc.Client('irc.chatbelgie.be', 'yourNick', {
    channels: ['#games'],
});
client.addListener('message', function (from, to, message) {
    console.log(from + ' => ' + to + ': ' + message);
});
```

Comment: Not a solution i expected but it works great THANKS!

Comment: Can you guide me via chat how you manage this so fast. If you have time for it

Comment: I simply visited that site and noticed it was just a web interface over an IRC server. I searched for an IRC client in node and wrote the answer, slightly modifying the code from the Basic Usage section from the manual to suite their IRC server